# $grid-margin-gutters from Foundation Zurb does not work as expected

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

In a project that I'm working at, I'm trying to achieve simple thing with Zurb Foundation 6 for Sites.
Over **1280px** grid gutters should be **20px**, under **1280px** grid gutters should be **10px**.
I've changed settings.scss as on the screenshot below, but anyway it doesn't work. 
Anybody faced the same problem in past??
I want to have in the **$grid-margin-gutters** map values for large and xlarge breakpoints.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone facing the same problem. **The answer is:** if this **$grid-margin-gutters** does not work as you expect - please make sure that inside a **$grid-margin-gutters** map you are putting all the breakpoints starting from the smallest one. So follow the pattern:

```
$grid-margin-gutters: (
   small: 10px, 
   medium: 10px, 
   large: 20px,
   yourCustomBreakpoint: 30px
);
```

And don't forget to add these custom breakpoints inside variable **$breakpoint-classes:** like the following:

```
$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large yourCustomBreakpoint xxlarge);
```

Works as expected right now, compile without any errors.